# Proof explanation, no two subsets of a set are subsets of each other

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients

I have a question about the following proof:

> **Question:**  Recall that there are $2^n$ subsets of an $n$-element set. For example, when $n = 4$, there are $2^4 = 16$ subsets of a 4-element set. Of these 16 subsets, 6 have two elements.
> When n = 6, there are $2^6 = 64$ subsets of a 6-element set. Of these 64 subsets, 15
> have two elements and 15 have four elements, while 20 have three elements.
> **The maximum number of subsets of an n-element set, n ≥ 3, such that no two subsets
> are subsets of each other is $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$.**

> **Proof:** The statement is false. If n = 6, then $\binom{6}{2} = \frac{6(6 − 1)}{2} = 15.$  However, no two of the 20 3-element subsets of a 6-element set are subsets of each other.

My question is: Isn't the "no two subsets are subsets of each other" satisfied for ALL 64 of the subsets of a 6 element set? That is, no 2 subsets are subsets of each other, since otherwise they would be equal and hence couldn't be in the same set.

Comment: Writing, e.g.,  $2n$ when you mean $2^n$ makes your post hard to read.  Writing $24=16$ makes the problem explicit.   [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the statement.  When it says "no two subsets are subsets are each other." it does NOT mean that it is not true that "A is  a subset of B AND  B is a subset of A".  It means that it is not true that "A is a subset of B OR B is a subset  of A".

Comment: @GeorgeIvey  Though $\binom n2$ is not the correct number even for the properly stated problem.

Comment: $\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}$ so you can include one but not the other. The proof says the claim is false because there are twenty subsets of size three and none of those can be subsets of each other because, as you said, they would have to be equal. Therefore, it is not true that the number of two element subsets is equal to the largest number of subsets with the property that none of them are subsets of each other.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also found the problem statement confusing. I would probably have said we have a maximal collection of subsets such that no set in the collection is a subset of any other. "Each other" suggests a symmetric relationship, which is not what we're concerned with.

Comment: You're right that "each other" fails to express what the author intended. Two sets that are subsets of each other are indeed equal.

Comment: To be fair I do not think the text expressed it correctly.  IMO it should not be "no two subsets are subsets of each other".  It should be "No subset is a subset of any other subset" or (less succinctly but closer to what the text said) "No two subsets are that one is a subset of the other".  To my parsing "no two subsets are subsets of each other" means just how the OP interpreted it.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you!